# Здраствуйте я только создал Jar Фаил на java в intelejIdea и хочу сделать из него живые обои. Это реально? или все делать заново в Android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здравствуйте! Я создал *Jar*  файл на *Java* в *Intellij IDEA*  и хочу сделать из него живые обои.

Это реально?

Или все делать заново в *Android Studio*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Здраствуйте

Привет!

> Я только создал *Jar* файл на *Java* в Intellij IDEA

Искренне поздравляю!

> и хочу сделать из него живые обои

Ваше желание похвально

> Это реально?

Да

> или все делать заново в *Android Studio*?

Совершенно не обязательно, главное, чтобы ваш код реализовывал требуемые вызовы, которые должны реализовывать живые обои. А где и как вы писали код - не имеет никакого значения.

Вы можете взять Android SDK, в его состав входит утилитка `dx`. При ее помощи можно созданные джары/классы сконвертировать в `DEX` файл, упаковать в *APK*, подписать, а потом выровнять (не подровнять!) утилитой `zipalign`. И живые обои готовы, хоть на рынке продавай! Ай, какие обои получатся, красивые, с помпонами и драконами!

Comment: вы просто лучший)